# Analyzing tritomous categorical variable between- and within-groups

Tags: categorical-data, proportion, age

I have data examining a decision task across age groups.  For the decision task, responses are categorical and coded into 3 possible decision types (A, B, C) that are mutually exclusive and exhaustive (i.e., a participant's response can be only one of the decision types).  This task was given to participants who were classified into 5 different age groups.  What I want to do:

- **Compare the proportion of decision types *across* age groups: i.e., Did participants in age group 1 make decision type A more frequently than participants in age group 2?**
- **Compare the proportion of decision types *within* age groups: i.e., Did participants in age group 1 make decision type A  more frequently than decision type B?**

For each of these analyses, I'd ideally like an omnibus test with complete resolution for follow-up (i.e., pairwise comparisons b/w age groups and decision types).

I initially re-coded decision type as a within-subjects variable (i.e., 1 on the decision type the participant responded with, 0 on the others) and ran it as a mixed ANOVA (Age Group X Decision Type), and though this allowed for the omnibus + post-hoc testing, it didn't seem appropriate given the nature of the DV.  I also looked at logistic regression, but this seems like a messy and cumbersome analysis (i.e., have to run a large number of individual regressions because logistic regression compares all groups to **one** reference group per regression--at least in SPSS).  Also, I'm not sure whether there are viable options for comprehensive post-hoc analyses via logistic regression (outside of more logistic regressions).

Any suggestions for more appropriate/parsimonious analyses to get at the two points above (+ guidance on practical implementation in SPSS/R)?

Comment: I edited the title changing trichotomous to use the proper Greek word roots.  Before proceeding with your question think more about whether you are conceptualizing age the best way.  I'm not sure "age group" is really meaningful.  Certainly you'll have some age variation within "age group".  See if you can recast this as "age continuous".

Comment: Frank, thanks for your feedback and correction!  Regarding your point about continuous age, we have also conducted a linear regression predicting an alternative  continuous measure of the DV (including linear & quadratic age terms as predictors).  This provided a nice picture of our data, but we want to say more regarding differences between specific age groups (i.e., do children make more errors than adults, etc) even given the within-group variation.  Would you recommend any analyses could answer these kinds of questions _while_ keeping age continuous?

Comment: You're thinking of artificial groups, which are almost always misleading and create artifactual effects at group boundaries.  I'd fit the age effect smoothly but flexibly and plot it along with confidence bands.  That is the most insightful approach, and free of artibrary decisions/forced boundaries.  It solves the problem of within-group heterogeneity.